# Show that $M$ is compact metric space if and only if all countable cover (not necessarily open) of $M$ have a finite subcover.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(M,d)$ metric space. Show that $M$ is compact if and only if all countable cover of $M$ have a finite subcover.

**Remark:** Note that the cover is not assumed to be open, it can be formed by any type of set.

I think hypotheses are missing, but I have not been able to find a counterexample or prove it.

This exercise I found in a book that for me is not very reliable since I have found other exercises with errors.

Comment: Hmmm, $$A_n = \{0\} \cup (1/n,1]?$$

Comment: It becomes true when we consider open covers, a metric space is compact if and only if it is countably compact.

Comment: What book is this from? Every book has errors. It be nice to have a global registry of known bugs for common texts :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Is a spanish book, http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.7440/j.ctt1b18tvk

Comment: @DanielFischer  thanks for your help.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca: Thanks! Unfortunately, despite many attempts, I seem to be a strict monoglot.